# C++, template specialization problem

Tags: c++, templates, specialization

I am having problems with template class specialization, see the code bellow, please.

```
template <typename T>
class Point
{
    private
            T x, y;
            typedef T Type;

    public:

            Point ( const T & x_, const T & y_) : x ( x_ ), y ( y_ ) {}
};

template <typename Item>
struct TItems
{
    typedef std::vector <Item> Type;
};


template <typename Item>
class Container
{
    protected:
            typename TItems <Item>::Type items;

    public:
            typedef Item type;
};
```

Is it possible to specialize Container class for Point ?

Updated question:

I tried the following code, is it valid?

```
template <typename T>
class Container < Point <T>  >
{

};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
return 0;

Container <Point <double> > points;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, yes, but your syntax isn't quite right. As it stands, the compiler doesn't know what `T` is, so you have to tell it that it is a template parameter:

```
 template<typename T>
 class Container<Point<T> > { };
```

Comment: Thanks, I corrected my code at the same time as you posted the answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

yes you can specialize your class with that type `Point <T>` .

**Edit:**

> I tried the following code, is it
>   valid?

If you've tried the following code ,don't you know whether it compiled or not ? 0_o

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
Container <Point <double> > points;
return 0; // return should be here nor program will exit before creating Container <Point <double> > points;
}
```

r

Comment: `_tmain` is not a legal function name, so the mere fact that it compiles doesn't really offer much help as to whether or not the code is legal.

Comment: I think he is using visual studio.

Comment: @Dennis, how is `_tmain` not a legal function name?  It's a valid identifier, and not even a reserved one.

Comment: @Ben: in the global scope, names beginning with an underscore are reserved. The important thing is that simply compiling code hints at accuracy, but does not guarentee it.

Comment: @Dennis: Reserved for the implementation, and this implementation specifies that it is a macro which expands to the name of the entry point (`main` or `wmain`).